# Unable to create sessionFactory

Tags: hibernate

This is the error massage from tomcat log,

```
03-Jan-2016 13:15:10.438 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-9] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [Login] in context with path [/Final] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:19)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
    at DB.PoolManager.<clinit>(PoolManager.java:36)
    at servletPack.Login.processRequest(Login.java:38)
    at servletPack.Login.doPost(Login.java:125)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/portal?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <mapping resource="DB/Cv.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="DB/Status.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="DB/StudentPreference.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="DB/Type.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="DB/Login.hbm.xml"/>`enter code here`
    <mapping resource="DB/Company.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="DB/Advisee.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="DB/Staff.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

hibernate.reveng.xml

PoolManeger.java (HybernateUtil.java)

```
package DB;

import javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

/**
 * Hibernate Utility class with a convenient method to get Session Factory
 * object.
 *
 * @author scc
 */
public class PoolManager {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
            // config file.
            //sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
             Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
            StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry
                = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

            // builds a session factory from the service registry
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Log the exception. 
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

I search a lot few had a some what close to this problem but no answerers
As I understand  sessionFactory creation is failing and I am using Hybernate4.3.x(jpa2.1), I can't find why and how this happening . If someone knows, please help.

Answer (score 1):

(1)you have not added below property in hibernate.cfg.xml

```
hibernate.connection.password
```

(2)you may try below code for loading sessionFactory , I am using this with hibernate version 4.3.7

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    /**
     * One connection from a DB requires only one instance of sessionFactory in
     * an application.
     * 
     * @return SessionFactory
     */
    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                .buildServiceRegistry();
        return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```

Comment: i am not using a password for this database so that why its not there so error remain the same but thanks for the try...

Comment: If your password is blank, then you may just use blank property like this : <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>

Comment: i did that but no change

Answer (score 0):

Create Session Factory And Session Like this

```
SessionFactory sessionfactory =  new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionfactory.openSession();
```